# how to start windows 10 appx (UWP) application from terminal (cmd)

Tags: cmd, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I have developer machine with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 Desctop and build UWP application (custom Unit Tests) in debug mode. I want to run debugged version of my UnitTests so try to start my Appx from python script (or just cmd.exe), but see only:

```
C:\Users\l_chayka\job_builds\unit_tests_win10\Debug>UnitTests.exe
The system cannot execute the specified program.
```

If I start Appx from Visual Stidio all works good, what should I do to make debugged version of UWP application start from terminal?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to start appx from command line:

1.Using window's startup menu. You can refer to Diogo's reply in this [post](http://Set%20objShell%20=%20WScript.CreateObject(%22WScript.Shell%22)). The syntax is like below. You can save to a vbs script and run in command line:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.SendKeys "^{ESC}"

WScript.Sleep 1000

objShell.SendKeys WScript.Arguments.Item(0)

WScript.Sleep 1000

objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

2. Using explorer.exe ( IE10)to launch the deployed app, such like this: "explorer.exe bingnews://". You can refer to this [post](http://www.itsjustwhatever.com/2012/10/28/launch-windows-8-metro-apps-from-a-desktop-shortcut-or-command-line/).
3. Programming to implement IApplicationActivationManager interface to load app. This is also based on window's registry keys to find the effective APPID. Detailed code could be find in this [post](https://powertoe.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/get-a-list-of-metro-apps-and-launch-them-in-windows-8-using-powershell/).

Hope this can help!

Comment: First suggestion `^{ESC}` is blocked in my Windows 10 machine. I don't know why. admin mode commandline also not working.